# React Reducer with some bad Syntax errors

Tags: reactjs, jsx, reducers

I'm a React beginner and trying to create a Reducer. First it was at least syntactically correct (not sure about the logic). After I added the IF and ELSE if the syntax is completely messed up:

[image]

The updated version which isn't working:

```js
import {addReducer} from 'reactn';

async function reducer() {

  addReducer('updateFormValues', (global, dispatch, props) => ({

    if(props.type && props.id) {
      return {
        event: {
          ...global.form,
          [props.type]: {
            ...global.form.[props.type],
            [props.id]: props.value
          }
        }
      }

    } else if (!props.type && props.id) ) {
        [props.value]: [global.form]

      }

    }))

  }
  export default reducer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `(global, dispatch, props) => ({` the `=> (` syntax with parenthesis after the arrow means return immediately. So what you've actually written is:

```js
(global, dispatch, props) => {
  return {
    if(props.type && props.id) {
      return {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Meaning everything after `=> (` is actually an object. Which makes since as to why you'd get syntax errors because `{ if(){..} }` isn't a valid object.

Remove the wrapping `()` in the function so that it is a function body and not a returned object. Then check and make sure all of your braces and parenthesis match up, and you should be good.

Make sure you fix `[props.value]: [global.form]` too. I'm assuming you intend to return it as an object. So make sure you do so.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and your explainations. Sadly i still  could not manage to produce some clean code ( I'm just not so experienced (3 weeks)).